# Map List of cars only for the previous selected country

Tags: flutter, list, dart, dictionary

Hello fellow Stackers,

I'd like to achieve that when I select a Country, let's say Hungary that then the car for Hungary are is displayed, in that case Truck and Car3, in the 2nd DropdownFormField. I can't find a Solution for that, I only can achieve that all cars from each country is displayed. I tried to use a forEach on the `model.countrys` at the 2nd Dropdown, but this is not possible because it does have a return type of void.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import '../../domain/model/vignette_model/country_model.dart';
import '../../domain/model/vignette_model/vignette_model.dart';

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomeScreen({
    super.key,
  });

  @override
  State<HomeScreen> createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  String? selectedValue;
  String? selectedVehic;

  VignetteModel model = VignetteModel(
    countrys: [
      const CountryModel(
        country: 'Austria',
        cars: [
          'Truck',
          'Car1',
        ],
      ),
      const CountryModel(
        country: 'Germany',
        cars: [
          'Truck',
          'Car2',
        ],
      ),
      const CountryModel(
        country: 'Hungary',
        cars: [
          'Truck',
          'Car3',
        ],
      ),
    ],
  );
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Home'),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(25),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            const SizedBox(height: 30),
            DropdownButtonFormField(
              items: model.countrys?.map((e) {
                return DropdownMenuItem(
                  value: e.country,
                  child: Text(e.country.toString()),
                );
              }).toList(),
              onChanged: (value) {
                setState(() {
                  selectedValue = value;
                });
              },
              value: selectedValue,
            ),
            if (selectedValue != null)
              DropdownButtonFormField(
                items: model.countrys?.map((e) {
                  return DropdownMenuItem(
                    value: e.cars,
                    child: Text('${e.cars}'),
                  );
                }).toList(),
                onChanged: (value) {
                  setState(() {
                    debugPrint(value.toString());
                    // selectedVehic = value.toString();
                  });
                },
                value: selectedVehic,
              )
            else
              const Text('empty'),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: The function you are searching for is `where`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have got a solution for you:

```
class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomeScreen({
    super.key,
  });

  @override
  State<HomeScreen> createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  CountryModel? selectedCountryModel;
  String? selectedVehicle;

  VignetteModel model = VignetteModel(
    countries: [
      CountryModel(
        country: 'Austria',
        cars: [
          'Truck',
          'Car1',
        ],
      ),
      CountryModel(
        country: 'Germany',
        cars: [
          'Truck',
          'Car2',
        ],
      ),
      CountryModel(
        country: 'Hungary',
        cars: [
          'Truck',
          'Car3',
        ],
      ),
    ],
  );
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Home'),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(25),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            const SizedBox(height: 30),
            DropdownButtonFormField<CountryModel>(
              items: model.countries.map((e) {
                return DropdownMenuItem<CountryModel>(
                  value: e,
                  child: Text(e.country.toString()),
                );
              }).toList(),
              onChanged: (value) {
                setState(() {
                  selectedCountryModel = value;
                });
              },
              value: selectedCountryModel,
            ),
            if (selectedCountryModel != null)
              DropdownButtonFormField<String>(
                items: selectedCountryModel?.cars.map((car) {
                  return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                    value: car,
                    child: Text(car),
                  );
                }).toList(), 
                onChanged: (value) {
                  setState(() {
                    debugPrint(value.toString());
                    selectedVehicle = value;
                  });
                },
              )
            else
              const Text('empty'),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Hope it helps! :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this was something I haven't thought about.

Just for your information, add at the first setState at the selectedCountryModel add also selectedVehicle = null;, because when you change the country then the vehicle dropdown throws an error when a vehicle is choosen.